# Хранить статус кнопки

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Столкнулся со следующей задачей: есть приложение с многочисленными фрагментами. В одном из фрагментов есть кнопка - "Начать", которую после нажатия я скрываю (gone) и делаю видимой кнопку "Закончить". При выходе из этого фрагмента и новом переходе в него - кнопки видимы "по-умолчанию", то есть не так, как должны быть. Как можно сохранять статус, или флаг кнопок, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "Начать" - куда-то записывалось, что процесс начался, и при заходе на форму, если этот статус актив - скрывалась кнопка?

Comment: А что вы начинаете и заканчиваете? Это что-то наверное живет независимо от фрагмента. Вот с этим и синхронизируете вид фрагмента, а не наоборот.

Answer (score 0):

Сохранить статус можно разными методами:
создать статическую переменную, сохранить в настройки, записать в базу или еще куда.

Что бы следить за неким фоновым процессом можно использовать **LiveData**, например

```
public class LoadingLiveData extends MutableLiveData<Boolean> {
    private static LoadingLiveData sInstance;

    public LoadingLiveData() {
        setValue(false);
    }

    public static LoadingLiveData getInstance() {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new LoadingLiveData();
        }
        return sInstance;
    }
}
```

Так например при старте процесса загрузки я передаю в LoadingLiveData true

```
LoadingLiveData.getInstance().postValue(true);
```

А при окончании false. А что бы узнать идет ли процесс

```
boolean isLoading = LoadingLiveData.getInstance().getValue()
```

Можно еще повесить наблюдатель за LiveData который к примеру будет отображать иконку процесса

```
LoadingLiveData.getInstance().observe(this, isLoading -> {
        if (isLoading != null) {
            if (isLoading) mLoadingView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else  mLoadingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```